# Upload a local website done in wordpress to an ovh server

Tags: wordpress, web, ovh

Given that I'm not so familiar with these kind of stuffs, I bought an ovh domain and I would like to upload my website I have developed so far in local. How can I transfer it to ovh servers?

Answer (score 0):

Ovh is just an online server. You can use the method which is given in following link to transfer your word press site from local computer to online ovh server.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/